# unknown type or namespace linq of system.xml

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to add reference to `XElement` in my C# Silverlight 4  project, and I get an error

> unknown type or namespace linq of system.xml

Do you know what can effect this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace you need should be `System.Xml.Linq` so add a

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: May need to add a reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll in the project first.

Comment: @Anthony: You are right - You should have kept your answer - it is more complete than mine.